# Cast to interface in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a .dll that works with C# and Visual Basic for Applications. In C# I have a function that works like this:

```
(cheese as OtherClass).SpecialFunction("Command", parameter, out object result)
```

How can I achieve the same result in Visual Basic for Applications?

I tried this:

```
Dim cheese As OtherClass
Dim useless_bool As Boolean
temp_bool = cheese.SpecialFunction("Command", parameter, result)
```

I added the boolean because the whole `SpecialFunction` returns a boolean and I thought I couldn't cast it otherwise. However, `Dim cheese As OtherClass` doesn't work. How am I supposed to cast an object to another class?

Comment: You have to set cheese to point to a concrete  instance of the class you wish to use.  You haven't done that in your code.  Its difficult to provide further advice because you don't provide enough information.  If you are trying to provide a class instance from your dll then you may need to ensure that the dll is com compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [that](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?893705-Casting-Object-to-Interface), I managed to cast.

It works like that:

```
Dim cheese2 As OtherClass
Set cheese2 = cheese
Dim temp_bool As Boolean
temp_bool = cheese2.CustomCommand("Command", Parameter, result)
```

Edit: As freeflow mentioned in a comment, I had to set `cheese` to point to a concrete instance of the class I wanted to use.